# Make 2 HTTP-requests in a session through Tor with the same exit-node

Tags: python, http, python-2.6, python-requests, tor

I would like to use the library requests to make two HTTP-requests within a session.
However I don't know whether the IP adresses will be the same for both HTTP-requests (within that session).

Can you tell me whether it will use the same IP (important for me) or whether Tor will use two different Exit-nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember, Tor changes routes after some pre-specified number of minutes. I'm tempted to say that the time period is 10 minutes, but I'm not entirely certain. Either way, so long as those two requests are made within that time-frame they'll have the same IP address.

Comment: Use subprocess to start tor, note the time. Test tor to make sure you're not using you're own IP address. If your test takes less than a minute (which it should) and your subsequent requests take less than 4 a piece, you're safe.